# Is there a way to override the DefaultSchema of a fluent nhibernate configuration in the map class?

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

### Background

I am working on a .net standard 2.0 library that is using FluentNhibernate 2.1.2.
Its fluent nhibernate configuration is set to use a default schema.

```cs
Fluently.Configure().Database(() => {
    var db = PostgreSQLConfiguration.PostgreSQL82;
    ...
    ...
    ...
    ...
    db.DefaultSchema('app');
});
```

### Problem

I am trying to add a class map that is under a different schema in the database than the default one.
Using `Schema('example')` in the class map's constructor just concatenates the schema to the default one.
Is there a way to override the schema for a specific mapping?

Comment: Can you just not set the `DefaultSchema` and then manually set it in each map class?

Comment: Yeah true but I wanted to avoid that since the solution I am working on has a lot of mappings already.